# Cannot find a word in sentence when using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I just started to learn how to write programs. In this program. I'm trying to find a word in a sentence while using the scanner. However, I ran into a problem. my code is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestOne {
    static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (pick == 5) {
            String sentenceFive = "i see you";
            String wordFive = "you";

            if (sentenceFive.contains(wordFive)) {
                System.out.println("Keyword matched the string");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("No match");
            }
        }  else if (pick == 6) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
            String sentenceFive = scn.nextLine();
            scn.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter a word");
            String wordFive = scn.nextLine();

            if (sentenceFive.contains(wordFive)) {
                System.out.println("Keyword matched the string");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("No match");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

`(pick==5)` works totally fine but `(pick==6)` returns "No match".
The `if` & `else` statements are both the same and my inputs for `(pick==6)` are also the same as the strings in `(pick==5)`. So I guess it's because of the scanner, right?

Comment: This code doesn't compile, and we don't know what you entered. Post a minimal compiling example, and tell us precisely what you entered. Use your debugger, or print the values of the variables.

Comment: Please upload the full code. Where is this 'pick' variable initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked, Please refer the comments

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
        String sentenceFive = scn.nextLine();
        // scn.nextLine(); Not needed unless reading another line
        System.out.println("Please enter a word");
        String wordFive = scn.nextLine();

        if (sentenceFive.contains(wordFive)) {
            System.out.println("Keyword matched the string");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("No match");
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PS C:\TEMP\Projects\BU> java Main
Please enter a sentence
i am sam
Please enter a word
am
Keyword matched the string
PS C:\TEMP\Projects\BU>
```